# docker --add-hostname not working for windows container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network, nano-server

I am trying to add host names to host file in the windows container with no success.

According to documentation, this should add an entry on host file

```
docker run -it --add-host me:127.0.0.1  microsoft/dotnet:nanoserver powershell
```

but i can't ping "me" from the container.

Looking up at host file i find no entry for me.

```
cat C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

returns only the entrys:

```
192.168.125.108    host.docker.internal
192.168.125.108    gateway.docker.internal
```

I also try to add by docker-compose file, but i am not familiar with the sintax:

**Here is my docker-compose.override.yml**

version: '3.4'
services:
  trfout_wsrv:
    extra_hosts:
    - "me:127.0.1.1"

```
image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}trfoutwsrv
build:
  context: .\TRFOUT\TRFOUT_WSRV
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

Comment: Are you trying to give the container access to the host?

Comment: It seems that there is an [open issue](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1455) ,especially for windows containers.

Comment: just trying to use domain names instead of ip address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like `--add-host` not supported on the window, As its says

```
--add-host=""      : Add a line to /etc/hosts (host:IP)
```

I do think there is `/etc/hosts` in Window. Also example given in documentation is ubuntun base.
[docker run  --add-host](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/)

Also below is the open issue on Docker Github

[Adding hosts for windows containers (--add-host, extra_hosts) does not work](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1455)

> @zachChilders The only way I managed to configure it was with echo...
>   PowerShell would not work for some reason...

```
RUN echo 10.0.0.1 somehost.domain.local >> "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"
```

Comment: [How can I add DNS entries to hosts file of a Windows Container?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63880160/3110834)

Answer (score 0):

Open your `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` and check a line as this:

```
192.168.xxx.xxx host.docker.internal
192.168.xxx.xxx gateway.docker.internal
```

if not exits, add it.

Now, you can add next flag

```
--add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway
```